# Bootstrap - spacing between columns in smaller steps than integer?

Tags: bootstrap-4, spacing

Probably a silly question - is there a way to define values that are not integer or probably in some other metric?

I have this code:

```
'''<header class="text-center pb-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3"> <img src="img/logo.gif" alt="logo" class="img-rounded shadow">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9 pr-4 pl-4">
                <div class="row">
                  <img src="img/spacer.gif" class="border-0" style="height: 13px; width: 0px;">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-0">
                      <img src="img/spacer.gif" class="border-0" style="height: 150px; width: 0px;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 shadow rounded" style="background-image: url('img/night_ride.jpg')">
                    <div class="row">
                      <img src="img/spacer.gif" class="border-0" style="height: 25px; width: 0px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="font-italic mb-1 text-center text-white">text</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
          </header>'''
```

Found `pr-4 pl-4` for spacing between columns here and it works - but with 4 it is a bit to small gap, with 5 its far to much gap, and with values below 4 I can hardly see any effect.

is there a way to define `pr-4,5 pl-4,5` or something like that?

Comment: Check this page please :  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: i know that there are different measurements in css, but in bootstrap i always find only integers w/o unit? i guess it would also be able to sort this problem with css - but i would like to know if there is a way in bootstrap-only?

Comment: Well , check this please : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/

Comment: ok,its not possible then,what a pity!should work for my opinion as the values are only 4 and 5 - and there is a lot of difference left between $spacer * 1.5 and $spacer * 3.probably it would be an option to add two tags with smaller values - i will try this!

Comment: Good luck Kern .

Comment: thank you! tried putting several divs with "col-md-0" and with spacings in smaller steps - seems to work on a quick look - so problem solved!